# How do I read time samples of audio files in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I want to write an app on Android to record snoring sounds of a sleeper and analyze it afterwards (i.e., not in real-time) for signs of a medical condition called obstructive sleep apnea.

The Android devices I've experimented with have voice recorders that produce a file format called .3ga.   I want to programmatically read in the audio file and look at the amplitude for each individual time-sample.  Then I can analyze that for patterns.  Would this be easier if I converted this to a different format, e.g., MP3, and if so how can I do that programmatically?

I did a Google search on this and most of the hits seemed to be related to audio recording or playback which are unrelated to what I'm trying to do.    I haven't coded anything yet because I don't know how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to do sample-based analysis on a raw audio signal, but the formats you mention are compressed. You will need to either deal with raw samples directly, or decompress the audio and then analyze.

Since you said you can do this work after-the-fact, why not upload to a server  and analyze there?

Comment: I'd like to keep the whole thing on Android so the user can see the results on his phone, or show them to his physician.    Either way I have to decompress the audio, so how I do that on Android?    Alternatively, I could write my own recorder and write directly to an uncompressed format.   Since high fidelity isn't required I could use a low sample rate/small sample (bits) size to keep the file from getting too big (assume 8 hours of sleep).   But what file formats does Android support for doing that?

Comment: Also, just because 3ga is a compressed format doesn't necessarily mean there's no way to access individual samples - it depends on whether Android/java has support for reading it.  For example JPEG is a compressed format but you can load it into a Bitmap class and read individual pixels that way.

Comment: In that case I'd just use something like the [AudioRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) to read samples from the mic and process directly. 
It's impractical to save all samples, so you'll want to use a "sliding window" approach to detect what you are looking for.

Comment: In "what" case?  We haven't established that there's no way to read/parse a 3ga file or convert it to another format.   Keep in mind that snoring does not require high fidelity - 8000 samples per second, 8 bits per sample, monaural is only 230,400,000 bytes for 8 hours of sleep.